# How can I tell if a slow-blow fuse with a fiberglass center is blown?

Tags: amplifier, fuses

I have a guitar amplifier fuse that I suspect is blown. It looks like a tightly wound spring. I assume the fiberglass center has somehow melted away.

Am I correct in assuming this missing center is shorting the circuit?

Comment: What markings are on the fuse? On the panel or board near the fuse? And do you have a multimeter to check it?

Comment: Fuses don't short, they open. A metallic piece in the fuse melts/vaporizes, opening/disconnecting the circuit.

Comment: how would a piece of glass cause a short circuit?

Comment: @jsotola technically, molten glass (while molten) can be conductive. But that is not pertinent to the operation of fuses.

Answer (score 12):

You check a fuse with an ohmmeter.

- Very low resistance = fuse is OK.
- Very high resistance (often displayed as OL on digital multimeters) = fuse burned out.

If the fuse is blown (open circuit) then there's probably something else wrong with the amplifier - if you replace the fuse it will probably blow again.

Comment: also often displayed as | on the left side of the screen (opposite end from 1)

Comment: It's mandatory to disconnect the amplifier from mains before even opening it and trying this; and for some amps, it's necessary to insure that the large capacitors are discharged to a safe level. Also, the results indicated in the answer assume at least one side of the fuse is disconnected. It's NOT QUITE ALWAYS indispensable to disconnect the fuse to assert that it's blown: if there's more than a few Ohms measured with both measurement polarities, then the fuse is blown. I second that the cause of a blown fuse should always be investigated.